# how to pass Extended ASCII characters through JNI via C++

Tags: c++, utf-8, java-native-interface, extended-ascii

I am trying to use JNI via VC++ and pass a custom directory in the classpath as a UTF-8 string
-Djava.class.path=c:\myDir\my.jar

This works well and I could find the methods in the jar using FindClass

But when the directory name contains any extended ASCII characters then FindClass returns NoClassDefFound exception. I guess this is becasue the JVM is not able to load the jar file and I am doing something wrong in passing the arguments.

Here is what I do 
1) Create a std::wstring jarPath(L"-Djava.class.path=C:\ÆËñœ\my.jar");
2) Convert the wstring to CP_UTF8 using WideCharToMultiByte 
3) copy the utf8String to optionString and call JNI_CreateJavaJVM

I have tried printing the convertyed utf8 to a log file just before calling the JNI_CReateJavaJVM and it prints perfectly.

Could somebody please tell if the CP_UTF8 (defined in windows SDK WinN;s.h) is not what the JNI expects?
How do I debug this problem, any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp16334) suggests that the option string must be in "the default platform encoding". That probably means you'd need to use CP_ACP. If your characters can't be represented in that encoding then I'm not sure there's much you can do.

(Would the file's short name be usable instead?)

Comment: I found the following bug against JVM  http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do;jsessionid=17ba063642304ad90e9249db234?bug_id=4858889

Comment: Hi Alan, CP_ACP worked well. But the probability that you said exists and there it migh fail, but anyway its much better than just supporting 127 ASCII characters only.

Comment: I tried giving relative paths to the JVM e.g. the JAR's are inside my products installation directory which also contains its own JVM (in the current installation directory). So I thought I will give the relative path to JVM. But this didn't work.

Comment: @Rahul: What about short names (GetShortPathName)? They're always basic ASCII characters I think. I'd have thought relative paths would work, as long as you set the current directory first.

Comment: @AlanStokes Short names (8.3 aliasing) can be disabled for performance.